# How To Listen For New Phase Success When Image Url Changes in AsyncImage SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI application that regenerates random background on every tap gesture and adds a quote to it.

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: backgroundImgUrl)) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .empty:
                Color.purple.opacity(0.1)
            case .success(let image):
                image
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .onAppear {
                        //code here happen for 1 time only even for every background change
                    }
                 //can I execute code here??? syntax error happens
            case .failure(_):
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.icloud")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            @unknown default:
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.icloud")
            }
        }
```

The problem when I try to add quotes with a random on-tap gesture it appears before the background gets updated. so I want to execute code when every new random background is generated but I couldn't. can you give me some hints, please?

onTapGesture code:

```
.onTapGesture {
        backgroundImgUrl = "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature&\(Int.random(in: 1..<6236))"
        
    }
```

Comment: can you show more of your code, especially your tapGesture scheme to add `quotes` (and what quotes are), so we can test executing code when every new random background is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this using `onChange`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var backgroundImgUrl = "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature&\(Int.random(in: 1..<6236))"
    
    var body: some View {
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: backgroundImgUrl)) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .empty:
                Color.purple.opacity(0.1)
            case .success(let image):
                image
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .onChange(of: image) { _ in   // <-- here
                        // code here happen for every image change
                        print("----> in onChange ")
                    }
            case .failure(_):
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.icloud")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            @unknown default:
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.icloud")
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            backgroundImgUrl = "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature&\(Int.random(in: 1..<6236))"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working like charm!! can you explain please ```_ in``` part?

Comment: value which we won't use right?

Comment: right, but you could have one, for example: `.onChange(of: image) { img in ... }`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by adding identifier, like

```
case .success(let image):
    image         
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .scaledToFit()
        .onAppear {
            // this works
        }
        .id(backgroundImgUrl)   // << here !! (tested Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5)
```

*Note: as new Image view is inserted and old is removed the default opacity transition effect might be visible. It can be mitigated, if not needed, with adding nil animation.*

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestRenewAsyncImageResult.swift)

Comment: it didn't work as expected .```onAppear``` block of code only executes once

Comment: See updated, tested with your additional code.

Comment: worked, thanks. can you elaborate more please why the order of modifiers matters in SwiftUI?

Comment: it's the correct answer but still quote is shown before the Image gets replaced :(